# Datetime is not in correct format in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on an application in which I'm using select boxes for date & time like
[image]

Follow up is a Jquery DatePicker but for time I used select boxes. 
While I am adding this date & time like this

```
  $hr = $this->input->post('time_hr');
  $min = $this->input->post('time_min');
  $sec = $this->input->post('time_sec');
  $time = $this->input->post('next_call') . ' ' . $hr .':' . $min . ':' . $sec;
  //var_dump($time);exit();

  'next_call_time' => date('Y-m-d h:m:s', strtotime($time))
```

to the database table. In time minutes are always 12 when entering minutes more than 12 (Like:*2014-12-24 09:**12**:00*)

Output on printing before inserting to database is:  `string(18) "12/24/2014 17:35:0"`

[image]

**Technology:**  PHP, MySQL, CodeIgniter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use H:i:s instead of h:m:s.

H is 24 hour, h is 12 hour, m is month, i is minutes.

Please take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Now this is working fine. I know it was a silly mistake but I was wondering why it is not working from last 2 days.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Salman: There was minimum time condition that's why i was not able to accept before that time.